# Navigate DOM tree (label-class-div) with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I've a DOM structure like this

```
div id=1
  div id=2
    div class=a
       label

  div id=3

  div id=4
    span class=aa
    span class=bb
    span class=cc
```

now, by a call in "label", I would like to change css of "cc" class; i would like to get access to it by DOM tree because the "id=1" div is iterated N times: how could I access to "cc" using jquery??

thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean in an event handler on the `label`, you can get to it use `parent().parent().parent().find(".cc")`, like so:

```
$("selector for the label").click(function() {
    var cc = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".cc");
    // ...
});
```

If you can possibly add a class to that top-level div (with `id=1`), that would be cleaner:

```
$("selector for the label").click(function() {
    var cc = $(this).closest(".top-level").find(".cc");
    // ...
});
```

---

From your comment below:

> it's a little bit different from my case: the label has an onClick function that calls a jquery-ajax call; at ajax response i have to call the change css function.

Using `onxyz` attributes in the markup is fairly old-fashioned, but you can still use it if you like, just make sure you pass `this` into the function you call:

```
<label onclick="doSomething(this)">...</label>

function doSomething(label) {
    var cc = $(label).parent().parent().parent().find(".cc");
    $.ajax({
        /*...misc params...*/
        success: function() {
            cc.css(/*....*/);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it's a little bit different from my case:
the label has an onClick function that calls a jquery-ajax call; at ajax response i have to call the change css function.

i've tried to use the following way:

label -> onClick= myFunction(this) ; 
ajax -> success -> myFunction(label) { var cc= label.parent().parent().parent().find(".cc"); }

but after ajax call, I receive "label.parent is not a function" error. anyone?

Comment: @SotirisAkisMitracos: It would have been useful to mention that in your question. I've added a bit to the answer.

Comment: @SotirisAkisMitracos: Re the edit to your comment: You get that error because you're trying to call a jQuery function (`parent`) on a non-jQuery object (`HTMLLabelElement`). You need to wrap the element in a jQuery object via `$(label)`. Amusingly, that's the exact name I used in the edit to the answer above while you were editing your comment. :-)